# angular custom drag and drop flow with image

Tags: angular, image, drag-and-drop

I want to achieve the below flow using drag and drop image. The same file is used by the flow1 and flow2. in Flow1 process A --> (after complete) Process B --> (after complete) Process C based on the scheduled datetime (first flow).

[image]

Lets say flow1 scheduled at 9AM  and flow2 at 3PM.

I will have these icons on left pan and I need to drag and drop to create the flow. Is there any similar kind of library or code I can use it for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ngx-graph which has all the features you've asked for. Take a look at the [demo](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/#quick-start). Here is the link in [github](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph)

Comment: But I don't think drag and drop feature can be made using this. This is useful for the graph display only

Answer (score 0):

There are many other commercial options but I don't suggest you .

Here you are :

[image: other options]

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I am not looking for a graph component. Left side I have the options of ProcessA, ProcessB and ProcessC . When I drag n drop the options it create like above flow.